# Why can't display scroll of div?

Tags: html, css

This is my html and css:

I want display 3 div on 1 line:

i set height of `div = 300px`

at div 2 i set `height:1500px`, but it auto expand div and not display scroll:

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>       
           .mainContent {
                display: table;
                width: 100%; /*Optional*/
                table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
                border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/              
            }
            .col {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 400px;
                overflow: scroll;
                height: 300px;
                border: 3px solid black;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="col">

                part 1
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                part 2
                <div id="resultTable" style="height:1500px;">


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                part 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why can't display scroll of div?

Comment: You using css "display: table;" and "display: table-cell;" in child so it's behaving like table cell. We know in table if any column grow then rest of the other's automatically grow up and keep them same height that's the reason not generating scroll.

Comment: I think the issue is you're using table layout. If you set your column divs to display:block, and float:left; then you'll get the ability to scroll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're using table layout. If you set your column divs to display:block, and float:left; then you'll get the ability to scroll back.

```
<style>       
       .mainContent {
            display: block;
            width: 100%; /*Optional*/             
        }
        .col {
            display: block;
            float:left;
            width: 400px;
            overflow: scroll;
            height: 300px;
            border: 3px solid black;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please use the comment feature. Or make your answer more complete with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Flex layout.

```css
.mainContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/              
}
.col {
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="col">part 1</div>
    <div class="col">part 2
        <div id="resultTable" style="height:1500px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        part 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex can't keep size of column when zoom out.

Comment: @DT zoomed? can you please explain the same?